# DataRow, DataColumn and DataTable not found when converting from rc1 to rc2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-1.0

Im converting my asp.net core project from rc1 to rc2. I am having trouble getting DataRow, DataColumn to work and now im getting this error on DataTables:
DataTable does not contain a constructor that contains 0 arguments;

I have already added these to the project.json file with no luck.

```
"System.Data.Common": "4.0.1-rc2-24027",
"System.Data.SqlClient": "4.1.0-rc2-24027"
```

Is there a work around?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same issue as well. Funny thing is that Microsoft has ported the base layer i.e. DataTable but not the DataRow & DataColumn. See section "Considered for porting" at [this link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/02/10/porting-to-net-core/).

Depending on what you are dealing with, I guess we are forced to use List or something similar.

Do let me know if you were able to come up with a work-around.

Comment: Got the same problem here...I'm trying to figure out how to use `SqlDataRecord` (I'm on ASP.NET Core 1.0), but the Dapper.Tvp nuget package is not compatible with ASP.NET Core. -> <-